# Call rails method periodically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want a rails method to be called automatically whenever the contents of a textfield is changed, or every n seconds. How can I do this?
The method is on the object's model definition.
Also, how can I get the content of the textfield?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require using some javascript.  I use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library to help me along.  I would search the net ('Google') "rails jquery" for some tutorials.

Or if you prefer another library check out [Best javascript libraries to work with rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951141/best-javascript-libraries-to-work-with-rails)

Once you have your javsacript library in place you will need some sort of script to monitor the input.  One way is to use a `keyup` event to listen for activity.  This script will then post your data to the server via ajax.

Comment: I already know how to check if a certain element changed. Thats pretty easy using rails
observe_field("content", :frequency => 1, :function => "alert('Element changed')")

I just don't know how to call the object's method.

Comment: Instead of using `observe_field("content", :frequency => 1, :function => "alert('Element changed')")` which will run some javascript use `observe_field("content", :frequency => 1, :url => "controller/method/path" :with => "'text=' + value" )`. This will pass the value to a method in your controller. You can then do your call to your model and return whatever to your view.

Comment: For monitoring the field ever n seconds you might want to checkout the settimeout js function .

Answer (score 2):

You may also use built-in rails helpers and write something like

```
<%= periodically_call_remote :url => {:controller=>'mailbox',
                                        :action => 'get_newest_messages'},
        :frequency => 15
%>
```

And then in the specified controller you may call needed method of a model.